# how to use map function to display data from array by two's

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I'm wondering if there's a good way I could map data from an array where I can display the items in groups of 2. An example would be displaying multiple divs from mapping an array like this:

Array:

`const sampleArray = [object1, object2, object3, object4]`

Desired output:

```
<div> 
  <object1 />  
  <object2 /> 
</div>

//next div container will contain object3 and object4
```

Comment: Not with just `map()` - it's for 1:1 conversion, not many:less. You're supposed to [chunk the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks) for that.

Comment: You CAN map into divs

Comment: Something like `const html = sampleArray.map((item,i) => i%2 ? \`<div>${sampleArray[i-1]}${sampleArray[i]}</div>\` : '').join("")`

Comment: @mplungjan yes, you can make `.map()` do many things which I'd argue is not meant to do. I do not think it should be (mis-)used for that, though. It's a very "when all you have is a hammer" way of problem solving.

Comment: My map example is on the borderline, but op is processing all the elements in the array

Comment: Yeah I agree with @VLAZ, I made something similar using `.join`, but I found it very messy and confusing.